# scroll to the top of page in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am designing the registration page in Reactjs .and I am doing manual validation. now what I want is after clicking onSubmit, the page should  **scroll to the top** to show all errors in the validation.I tried but failed to achieve this.is there anyone who will help me

Comment: You can add `id` to an element and use `href` to that particular id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you task is to scroll to errors rather than scrolling to top, you can try this.

```
import React { useRef } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
    const errorRef = useRef(null);

    const onSubmitHandler = () => {
        ...
        errorRef.current.scrollIntoView();
    }

    return (
        ...
        <div ref={errorRef} className='error-container'>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    );
}
```

Note: Still you want to try scroll to top you can try this.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

or

```
window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This line of code works for me

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```